# how to get back to English default code page?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, localization

I've been debugging an application as to why double-byte character languages were not showing up. Internally, the code stores all strings as char* even though it converts it appropriately at display time.

I solved it for Japanese and Russian by using WideCharToMultiByte() by using the appropriate language codes. Japanese for example uses a code page of 936. Once I set it up, it worked like a charm. And there were some steps of installing languages and language packs too.

However, somehow my machine has got into a weird state where it wants files to be opened in that state.

One perfect example is (opening in Japanese Shift-JIS):

```
//Copyright � 1996-2008
```

But the unedited file (in source control) shows up like it should:

```
//Copyright © 1996-2008
```

Certain files like the snippet above barf when I try to compile them -- and they are part of an SDK that I'm not meant to be editing and it never happened to me before, and it is not effecting anyone else on the team.

The error I get is:

1>e:\projects-----\sdk\sdkheader.h : error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
1>e:\projects-----\sdk\sdkheader.h : warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the current code page (932). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss
1>e:\projects-----\sdk\sdkheader.h : warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the current code page (932). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss

Whenever I try to open the file "with encoding" it shows Japanese Shift-JIS as the top choice. I can save it as Unicode, and it compiles fine, but altering SDK files is not an option.

My keyboard is set to ENG, and rebooting and reverting files doesn't solve the problem. I seem to be perpetually stuck in this mode and can't figure out how to go back to normal. I am running on Windows 8.

Has anyone else been hit with this maddening bug? I am looking for ideas.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it was my system locale was set to Japanese. In Windows 8, there are several different areas to set this stuff up and somehow I missed that one.